# Draw the screen to a window using StretchBlt()

Tags: windows, gdi

I'm working on a program to capture the screen and then draw it on a window.

This is the drawing thread function:

```
void DrawFunc(void*hwnd)
{
    HDC windowdc=GetDC((HWND)hwnd);
    HDC desktopdc=GetDC(GetDesktopWindow());
    for(;;)
    {
        RECT rect;
        GetClientRect((HWND)hwnd,&rect);
        StretchBlt(windowdc,0,0,rect.right-rect.left,rect.bottom-rect.top,desktopdc,0,0,1920,1080,SRCCOPY);
    }
}
```

The problem is StretchBlt is too slow(about 20 fps)
What should I do to improve the performance?
Thanks.

Comment: You have an endless loop! Is it really what you want?